# How do I disable/enable a module on all sites within a multi-site Drupal installation using drush?

Tags: drush, multi-sites

As an admin of a multi-site Drupal installation, I want to make module changes to all sites within that platform.  On a regular basis, I want to disable/enable a set of modules to ensure consistency across all of the sites.

Using drush (any version 4.x, 5.x, or 6.x is acceptable), how can I perform this task without repeating the same command across each site?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drush has the ability to interact with each site within a multi-site installation via the @sites argument.  Anytime you are within the directory structure of your platform, the drush @sites command will target all sites rather than a single/no site.  In this way, *any* drush task can be accomplished across all sites.

Some concrete examples:

- Disable the dblog (core database logging) and devel module on each site

  ```
  drush @sites dis dblog devel -y
  ```
- Enable the speedy module on each site

  ```
  drush @sites en speedy -y
  ```
- Change the admin theme for all sites

  ```
  drush @sites vset --yes admin_theme "ember"
  ```
- Check to see if any sites in the platform have the cdn module enabled

  ```
  drush @sites pml --no-core --type=module --status="enabled" -y | grep cdn
  ```

These (and many more commands) work with any version of drush >= 4.x

Comment: After updating to Drush 8 I also had to specify the root path to the installation - `--root=/c/path/to/drupal` - otherwise running commands with `@sites` would crap out after the `Continue?` prompt. Bypass by adding this to aliases.drushrc.php file: `$aliases['sites']['root'] = '/c/path/to/drupal';`

Comment: +1 for pml on all sites with `drush @sites pml --no-core --type=module --status="enabled" -y | grep cdn` and to point out that the **-y** is of outmost importance! Also note that the command does not need to be launched at the sites level but also in any directory within.

Answer (score 0):

**And also to add with above answer,**

if you have 3 sites under sites folder. sites/all , sites/new , sites/dev and now assume "some_module" is installed and enabled in all 3 sites.

if you want to disable "some_module" only in "new" and "dev" sites

Step 1 : `cd DRUPAL_DIR/sites/new`

Step 2 : `drush dis some_module`

Step 3 : `repeat Step 1 and Step 2 for dev sites as well`