# How to create a module Dependency Graph?

Tags: 7

I am running a D7 site with 164 enabled modules. I need to create a module dependency graph so that I can get a better understanding of the module dependencies and find out which modules are critical.

I have checked out https://drupal.org/project/drush_mm but the page says it is obsolete and not present for D7.

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the sandbox drush module [dependency_analysis](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/elephant.jim/2293323)

It provides a drush command that produces a dependency graph using graphviz.  For me, I found that it was a simple matter of installing graphviz using homebrew:

```
$ brew install graphviz
```

And then follow the [project page description](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/elephant.jim/2293323).

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [Module Filter](https://drupal.org/project/module_filter), it quickly find the module you are looking for and with filter option and category.

> The modules list page can become quite big when dealing with a fairly
>   large site or even just a dev site meant for testing new and various
>   modules being considered. What this module aims to accomplish is the
>   ability to quickly find the module you are looking for without having
>   to rely on the browsers search feature which more times than not shows
>   you the module name in the 'Required by' or 'Depends on' sections of
>   the various modules or even some other location on the page like a
>   menu item.

Take a look at [Enabled Modules](https://drupal.org/project/enabled_modules) (enabled_modules) module provides lists of all enabled modules on a website.

> These features are useful for moving sites to a whole new code base
>   and rebuilding fresh with only the modules actually in use, or doing
>   clean up on your modules folders.

and also [Views System](https://drupal.org/project/views_system) module extends the Views module and allows to create customized lists (pages, blocks) of modules, themes, and theme engines that are or have been installed in Drupal's file system.

Using Drush check this [List of all active modules used in a site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44432/list-of-all-active-modules-used-in-a-site).

Comment: Bala I am not looking for filtering or finding the installed/enabled modules. I am looking for the module dependency chart within my site :)

Comment: @GokulNK I searched completely, no modules present to list the dependencies and small info using drush http://www.drupaltonight.com/drupal-articles/using-drush-get-list-enabled-modules

Answer (score 0):

[Graph API](https://www.drupal.org/project/graphapi) can do this. After installation, it shows you the Module dependencies at `/admin/modules/graph`.