# Action on module enable?

Tags: 7, hooks

I want to show a message when a module is being enabled. I used `hook_modules_enabled` and it shows me the message while enabling a new module.

Now I need the currently enabled module machine name in the hooks argument.
But `hook_modules_enabled($modules)` returns an **array of modules** in the argument.

*Eg:*

When **views** is enabled, I need to set a message as:

> "**Views** Module is enabled"

Here I need "views" (i.e. the module name) as argument in `hook_modules_enabled` in order to print it in message but it returns me an array.

How can I achieve this. Is there any other hook for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument `$modules` in `hook_modules_enabled($modules)` returns an array of modules enabled. You should loop through the array to print the message.

Note: But only machine name of the module will be in the array.

For eg:

```
function MY_MODULE_modules_enabled($modules) {
  foreach ($modules as $module) {
    // To get Module Name 
    $module_info = system_get_info('module', $module);
    $module_name = $module_info['name'];
    //Loop through the modules and set the message. 
    $msg= "$module_name is enabled";
    drupal_set_message(t($msg), 'status', FALSE);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`hook_module_enable()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_enable/7) should do the job unless I'm missing something from your question.

> Perform necessary actions after module is enabled.
>
> The hook is called every time the module is enabled. It should be
>   implemented in the module's .install file. The implementation can rely
>   on the .module file being loaded.

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any other hooks that you could invoke; you could keep track of modules yourself, compare it with what you get in `hook_modules_enabled()` and then do whatever you want for each of the enabled/installed modules.

Here are general steps:

1. Upon installation of your custom module (or in update hook), save the snapshot of what is installed in the system at the moment. This would go into `.install` file and you could use part of the code from [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/44442/10041). Querying directly the `{system}` table might even work. Store everything as an array using `variable_set()`.
2. Use `hook_modules_enabled` (or `hook_modules_installed`) to compare the new list with the old one. Store differences in a separate array (e.g. `array_diff()`).
3. For each of the newly installed/enabled modules perform your action.
4. Update the custom variable for storing the list of modules using `variable_set()`.

Let me know if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: do you mean I have to take the difference between the module list before installing a new one and after it. In order to get the currently installed module name?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant.