# Cancelling user account set draft pages to published

Tags: 8, nodes, users

When we cancelled a user account using the `Delete the account and make its content belong to the Anonymous user` method, we found that the author was set to `Anonymous` for the pages they were set as the `Author`, as expected. The problem is that many pages that were set to `Draft` were then updated to have their `Author` set to `Anonymous` and `published`, which is not a desired outcome. These drafts were never published and always kept in that state.

We have a view that pulls all pages that are published and content type = `Basic Page`. This started to pull in all the `draft` pages because they were set to `published` after the user account was cancelled.

**How can we cancel an account without publishing pages that were are set to `Draft` moderation state?**

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create 10 draft  `Basic Pages` (do not publish) where the `Author` is set to `content admin`
2. Cancel the user account for `content admin` by using `Delete the account and make its content belong to the Anonymous user` method.
3. Under `/admin/content`, observe the pages are now in `published` state with `Author` set to `Anonymous`

Current modules being used for revision:

1. `workbench`
2. `workbench_moderation`

Comment: If this is like you describe perhaps it should be reported as a bug in the drupal core issue queue.  Have you tried reproducing this behaviour with a clean install and minimal modules enabled ? perhaps it could be the fault of a contrib module ?

Answer (score 0):

Just did a test with the steps you provided.  I tried with just 1 node unpublished and cancelled the user and the node was assigned to the anonymous user BUT the node stayed unpublished.  I don't see any reason why the result would be any different if I tried with 10 nodes.

I believe a contrib/custom module is at fault.  See if you have any modules that deal with publishing/unpublishing content you have to disable them and test if the problem is gone.

If the above does not help I would try to disable all modules one by one and testing to see if the problem is gone on each step.  Once you find the problematic module you can post the results in the issue queue and you might also discover a patch resolving the issue.

You can also post a [list of your enabled modules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44432/list-of-all-active-modules-used-in-a-site) and someone might be able to spot a module that could be a potential candidate to be causing this behaviour.

Comment: we are using `workbench` and `workbench_moderation` that may impact it, but I have not seen any issues yet. I will check again.